# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 13 elements, new values have 2 elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have looked at the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) about the hierarchical indexing in Pandas. I tried testing it with extracted data from an URL, but I am, clearly, missing something:

```
# creating an array of rows
rows = []

# making a for loop to append every player from every 'td' instance
for r in container.select('tr'):
    rows.append([col.text.strip() for col in r.select('td')])

zipped = zip(*rows)

# first row needs to have the header of the table on the website
csvfile = pd.DataFrame(zipped)
csvfile.columns = rows[0]
```

I thought about creating an empty dataframe of 13 columns, but I am not sure whether that will solve my problem

What I am trying to do is to create 13 columns, where each column has some data, which I have already extracted.

EDIT:

The extracted data looks like:
[image]

What I want, more specifically, is to put the left side (Column A) as a row instead, and put the right side under each.

Comment: It looks like your DataFrame has 13 columns, and you are trying to set the names of these columns to a list of length 2, which obviously won't work. To update the names of 13 columns, you need to give it a list of 13 elements. What does printing `rows[0]` show?

Comment: It shows the first piece of data I want to split

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'split'. Can you edit your question to show what your DataFrame looks like, and what `rows` looks like?

Comment: @Ben: Have done it

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, you want to transpose your DataFrame, i.e. swap the rows and the columns. You can do this with `csvfile.T`. Depending on whether column A in your spreadsheet is the index in your DataFrame, you may need to update the column names to the first row in this transposed DataFrame, and then drop the first row.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you! By "and then drop the first row", do you mean to write `zipped = zip(*rows[1:])`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165574/discussion-between-ben-and-bab).